# UITapGestureRecognizer with UIImageView works only in the top position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

When I add Gesture for UIImageView inside UITableView, it works only in the top of position when Im trying tap on the center of any (x,y) dimensions it doesn't work

This my code:

```
cell.mainImage.tag = indexPath.section;
[cell.mainImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(likeTappedDouble:)];
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapped.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
tapped.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
tapped.delegate = self;
[cell.mainImage addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
```

Look at the image [HERE](http://d.pr/i/Yvpg) to get the point please.

Any idea ?
EDIT

When I set the UITapGesture for the cell it works well, but I want to understand why the Gesture works only on the top position of UIImageView !!

```
[cell addGesture ...]
[cell setUser ...]
```

Comment: Why the UIImage view in a UITableView - what's the structure / relationship between the two ?

Comment: What is the size of the cell you're placing this image view in?

Comment: @0x7fffffff it is 315

Comment: @Ohnomycoco each section has two rows, the first row has UIImageView

Comment: But funky imo - a UITableViewCell already has a delegate method to handle taps (didSelectRowAtIndexPath).

Comment: @Ohnomycoco could I control number of taps with didSelectRowAtIndexPath ? that's why I use UITapGesture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this type of situations happen when the parent of your imageView is smaller than your imageView.

I suspect that your cell has an height inferior to the imageView or that you have some sort of container that has the frame smaller than the imageView.

In these situations is useful to use an application like [Reveal](http://revealapp.com/) to help you out debugging the issue.

Comment: No problem. I hope it helped fixing your issue :)